# Undefined reference to a function for cuda implementation

Tags: c++, cuda

I have wrote a cuda application which has a `main.cpp` that includes a `Common.h` file

```
#include "Common.h"
int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
   ...
   DeviceFunc(a_h , numvar , b_h); //Showing the data
   ....
}
```

Then, `Common.h` contains:

```
 #ifndef __Common_H
 #define __Common_H
 #endif
 void DeviceFunc(float * , int , float *);
```

Also, `DeviceFunc.cu` is in the same folder:

```
 #include<cuda.h>
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include "Common.h"
 __device__ __global__ void Kernel(float *, float * ,int );
 void DeviceFunc(float *temp_h , int numvar , float *temp1_h)
 {
    float *a_d , *b_d;
    //Memory allocation on the device
    cudaMalloc(&a_d,sizeof(float)*(numvar)*(numvar+1));
    cudaMalloc(&b_d,sizeof(float)*(numvar)*(numvar+1));

    //Copying data to device from host
    cudaMemcpy(a_d, temp_h, sizeof(float)*numvar*(numvar+1),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Defining size of Thread Block
    dim3 dimBlock(numvar+1,numvar,1);
    dim3 dimGrid(1,1,1);

    //Kernel call
    Kernel<<<dimGrid , dimBlock>>>(a_d , b_d , numvar);

    //Coping data to host from device
    cudaMemcpy(temp1_h,b_d,sizeof(float)*numvar*(numvar+1),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //Deallocating memory on the device
    cudaFree(a_d);
    cudaFree(b_d);
 }

 }
```

Now when I compile the code with `nvcc -o main main.cpp`, I get this error `main.cpp:(.text+0x3a0): undefined reference to 'DeviceFunc(float*, int, float*)'`

What is the problem

Comment: You'll need to build the DeviceFunc.cu into an object and link it into your main application.

Comment: if cuda is installed in the usual location /usr/local/cuda then you can look at the libraries in /usr/local/cuda/lib.  Some of them will have up to 3 numbers at the end of their names such as 4.1.28 or 5.0.35  Those numbers will tell you the cuda version 4.1.xx = cuda 4.1, 5.0.xx = cuda 5.0   Use ls /usr/local/cuda/lib or whereever cuda is installed on your server.    Or if the samples/SDK are built, you can run the deviceQuery sample and it will tell you the cuda version.

Comment: /usr/local/cuda/lib is 4.0.17

Comment: probably the simplest approach on cuda 4.0 is to edit the contents of DeviceFunc.cu into your main.cpp file.  Then change the name of main.cpp to main.cu   Then compile with nvcc -o main main.cu   I'm flying blind a bit here, since you haven't shown the contents of those files.  For example in DeviceFunc.cu I see that there is a forward reference to a kernel but no actual kernel (function) definition.  So I am assuming that is somewhere later in DeviceFunc.cu

Comment: post edited. I also tried pasting the content of `DeviceFunc.cu` to `main.cpp` and rename `main.cpp` to main.cu. However this time I get `/tmp/tmpxft_000067d6_00000000-13_main.o: In function 'DeviceFunc(float*, int, float*)':
tmpxft_000067d6_00000000-1_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to 'Kernel(float*, float*, int)'`

Comment: That's because you have no actual kernel definition in any of your files.  Where is the kernel function defined?  You need a file somewhere that has the following definition in it: __ global__ void Kernel(...  with a real definition of a function, not a forward reference which is what is in your DeviceFunc.cu   Fundamentally your project code is incomplete.

Comment: Under CUDA 4.0 it's probably not necessary to edit everything into a single file.  Your project appears to be structured so that you could build it with a command like this: __nvcc -o main DeviceFunc.cu main.cpp__   However this still will not work if you have no definition for the kernel in any of the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Undefined function reference occurs when the compiler **finds the prototype of the function** and **don't find the reference to the function during link**. To avoid this linking error, you should 1) compile-link whole files at one command, or 2) separate the compile and link process. I recommend the latter as follows:

```
nvcc -c main.cpp
nvcc -c DeviceFunc.cu
nvcc -c Kernel.cu
nvcc main.o DeviceFunc.o Kernel.o -o main
```

NOTICE that your shown codes miss the file containing the body `Kernel` function. I've supposed the body of `Kernel` function is included in `Kernel.cu`.

Comment: So...if there is no nvcc -c Kernel.cu command, how and where would you add it?